# Soundclound embed failed in firefox

Tags: firefox, embed, soundcloud

I found a bug with the SoundCloud embed. Randomly, the sound does not start on Firefox (3.6 to 12)

Everything works fine on Google Chrome or Internet Explorer.

You can see it here: http://clichesdecampagne.franceinter.fr/story/nous-sommes-le-peuple-de-france#item-4f6b9b31da7f5cec3b45fd38

Any idea ?

Answer (score 3):

Weird. I'm able to reproduce it on the site, but when embedding the same widget in another page it works fine. I'll forward it to our widget developers and see if they have an clue.

Comment: Johannes, thank you for your response. Do you have news about that? The problem seems to occur randomly. Sometimes the sound is played, sometimes not. But only on Firefox, other browsers everything is ok

Comment: Is there any more news on this? I'm having this issue as well.